# ByteArray - Error #2058: There was an error decompressing the data

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm making a data formatter for a game i'm making. it's a fighting game, and it'll import formatted and compressed character/stage data, making it easier for me to make DLC or expansion content if i decide to. it also keeps the data loading to a minimum!

anyhow, here's how i'm going about it:

character/stages need 1 sprite sheet and 1 metadata JSON

1. extract bitmapData from image and save into a variable
2. load and encrypt JSON string using a combination of xor and base64 encryption (decrypts fine)
3. make object and put them both into it -> `{ sheet: [bitmapData], meta: [cryptString] }`
4. write that all into a ByteArray and compress using `byteArray.compress();`
5. write byteArray into a file and save it

it's fairly straightforward i think, but when i try to decompress one of those files (using `byteArray.uncompress();` of course), i get this error in FlashDevelop:

```
[Fault] exception, information=Error: Error #2058: There was an error decompressing the data.
```

***BUT***, right before that, it traces the data correctly!

```
loaded ucd name: dummy
loaded ucd json: {"stats":{},"hitboxData":{},"animationData":{},"name":"dummy"}
```

is this a bug?? do i have to worry about it messing something up? if i end up doing expansion characters, i want to be able to make this data formatter a public tool so people can work on their own characters or stages, like [MUGEN](https://www.google.com/search?q=MUGEN&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), but easier.

sorry if this is too detailed or whatever, but this is my first time asking a question and i wanted to make sure there was no misunderstandings :>

Comment: Hmm, what algorithm are you using on the `compress` and `uncompress` methods? Have you tried using other algorithms, such as zlib or lzma?

Comment: im using the default (no parameters). that'd be zlib. i've tried lzma, same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, i finally found out what it was! for some odd reason, the loader i was using ran the onComplete function twice...at least it looks like it-- so it tried to decompress the data twice. i didn't run onComplete twice or anything, so that's weird.

still trying to figure out what caused that, but for now, i just made a `resetLoader()` method where it closes the loader and nullifies all of it's variables. worked like a charm.